# stochastic discount factor transformation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma, stochastic-discount

I have $$\frac{dM_t}{M_t}=-\frac{\mu}{\sigma} dW_t + \gamma_t dB_t, \tag{1}$$ where $B_t$ and $W_t$ are two independent Brownian Motions, which was further  presented as $$ M_t=\exp \left( -\frac{\mu}{\sigma}W_t - \frac{1}{2} \frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2}t + \int_0^t \gamma_s dB_s -\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \gamma_s^2 ds \right) \tag{2}$$

can anybody explain how $(1)$  was transitioned into $(2)$?

Comment: Made some stylistic changes and typo corrections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply Ito's lemma to $\ln M_t$, we obtain that
\begin{align*}
d\ln M_t &= \frac{1}{M_t} dM_t -\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{M_t^2} d\langle M, M\rangle_t\\
&=-\frac{\mu}{\sigma} dW_t + \gamma_t dB_t -\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{M_t^2}\left(\frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2} + \gamma_t^2\right)M_t^2dt\\
&=-\frac{\mu}{\sigma} dW_t + \gamma_t dB_t -\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2} + \gamma_t^2\right) dt.\tag{Eq. 1}
\end{align*}
Here, since $dM_t=M_t\big[-\frac{\mu}{\sigma} dW_t + \gamma_t dB_t\big]$,
\begin{align*}
d\langle M, M\rangle_t = \left(\frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2} + \gamma_t^2\right)M_t^2dt.
\end{align*}
From $(\textrm{Eq.} 1)$, 
\begin{align*}
\ln M_t - \ln M_0 &= \int_0^t\left[-\frac{\mu}{\sigma} dW_s + \gamma_s dB_s -\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2} + \gamma_s^2\right) ds\right]\\
&=-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}W_t - \frac{1}{2} \frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2}t + \int_0^t \gamma_s dB_s  - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \gamma_s^2 ds.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
M_t = M_0 \exp\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}W_t - \frac{1}{2} \frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2}t + \int_0^t \gamma_s dB_s  - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \gamma_s^2 ds\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: where the $M_t^2$ in the second line comes from?

Comment: @Michal: See my updates.

Comment: I can see that integrating both sides and solving for $M_t$  $$ \begin{align*}
d\ln M_t &=-\frac{\mu}{\sigma} dW_t + \gamma_t dB_t -\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2} + \gamma_t^2\right) dt.
\end{align*}$$ gives the equation (1), but I don't quite follow the condition for $M_0=1$

Comment: @Michal: See further updates.

Comment: in which case  the $M_t=0$ ? does the safe rate equal zero imply that?

Comment: @Michal: $M_t$ can not be zero based on the given dynamics. I do not know what is the safe rate. For any quantity, the initial value is assumed to be known. You do not have to assume that $M_0=1$, but, then you need to have a multiplier for your equation $(2)$.

Comment: sorry I meant $M_t=1$, this assumption is not quite clear to me, I mean looking at a problem what would allow / indicate that we can assume that indeed $M_t=1$? what is interpretation of it?

Comment: @Michal: Do you mean that $M_t$ is a constant? Note that, you may be provide with the initial $M_0$, or you can assume that $M_0=1$. I do not know why you want to say that $M_t=1$. If that is the case, you do not have to model it using an SDE as it is a constant. My answer above is based on the SDE you provided.   You can force it to be a constant by assuming that $\mu=0$ and $\gamma_t=0$, for all $t$.

Comment: @Michal: I removed the last sequence in my answer, if that confused you. Note that, you need to have the initial value $M_0$ in front of the exponent.